# proof tree latex using bussproofs

Tags: packages, logic, bussproofs, prooftrees, ebproof

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{P}
\AxiomC{$\neg P,Q$}
\BinaryInfC{Q}
\AxiomC{E}
\AxiomC{F}
\BinaryInfC{G}
\UnaryInfC{H}
\BinaryInfC{R}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used bussproof for producing proof trees above, but I got quite different result (tree below). can someone edit the latex above??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$P$}
\AxiomC{$\neg P,Q$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize Res}
\BinaryInfC{$Q$}
\AxiomC{$\neg Q,R$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize Res}
\BinaryInfC{$R$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```